# Adding a class to Fullcalendar Allday tag

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I would like to add a class to the allday row in agendaDay view to highlight it when the user selects it.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prevYear,prev,today,next,nextYear',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,listMonth'
    },
    defaultView: defaultView,
    navLinks: true,
    eventColor: 'blue',
    allDaySlot: true,
    height: "auto",
    events: {title: 'All Day Event', start: '2018-03-01',id: 999},
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        if(view.name != 'agendaDay'){ 
            $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
            $("td[data-date=" + date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "]").addClass("fc-state-highlight"); 
        }
        if(view.name == 'agendaDay'){ 
            $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
            $('[data-time="'+date.format('hh:mm:ss')+'"]').addClass("fc-state-highlight");
        }
        if (clickTimer == null) {
            clickTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                clickTimer = null;
                console.log("single");
                ///Single Click code here

                console.log(date.format());
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay', date);
                ///
            }, 500)
        } else {
            clearTimeout(clickTimer);
            clickTimer = null;
            console.log("double");
            ///Double Click Code here

        }

    }
});
```

Is it possible to add a class when the user clicks on it and if not where in the fullcalendar.js file should i add a class to it?

The css is:

```
 .fc-state-highlight {
        background:cyan;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite straightforwardly, for both "month" and "agenda" view types, like this:

JS:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
        left: 'prevYear,prev,today,next,nextYear',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,listMonth'
    },
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
        $("td[data-date="+date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"]").addClass("highlight");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight
{
  background-color:red;
}
```

I think your main difficulty was that the "fc-state-highlight" class you were using doesn't actually do anything.

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/436/ for a working demo.

You can of course adjust it if you want a different colour, or you only want the highlight to occur in more restricted circumstances etc.

Comment: i do have css to highlight the area but when i use your code it highlights the entire day instead of just the allday row or normal timeslot